# Extract fields ids and text from a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I want to make a simple app with JS that identies the form fields 
 which includes the id of the field and its corresponding Text.

For example, for the following site: https://freeditorial.com/en/register

[image]
 I want for each textbox the id, and the text. For the first one this will be:

> text: Email
>    id: "user_email"

I can do it with the following code:

```
form = document.getElementsByClassName("control-group")
form[0].innerText
form[0].querySelector("input").id
```

The problem is that this depends on the class name, which can change for each site. 
Is there a way to get this same data from the form?

I'm trying with:

```
var site_forms =  document.forms
```

If I check the text of the form the data seems to be all there:

```
site_forms[0].innerText
```

this is a segment of it:

```
<input id="user_role_ids" name="user[role_ids]" type="hidden" value="2">
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="user_email">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
  </div>
</div>
<span id="erroremail" class="rightCol error"></span>
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="user_name">Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="user_last_name">Last Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="user_username">Name by which you publish</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" value="" name="user[username]" id="user_username">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="user_country_code">Country</label>
  <div class="controls">
  <select id="user_country_id" name="user[country_id]">
    <option value="">Country</option>
    <option value="3">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="6">Albania</option>
```

But I don't find a reliable way of extracting it.

Comment: Look into the [`FormData API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). It extracts all `name` and `value` pairs from each input element whenever a `<form>` element is given as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may benefit from [`FormData()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData).

With that you simply need to build up `formData` object with `FormData()` constructor:

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm'),
      formData = new FormData(myForm)
```

Extract all of its entries either into array of key (`name` attributes of `<input>` nodes) value pairs:

```
const formEntries = [...formData.entries()]
```

Or object:

```
const formEntries = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
```

Or you may get individual values, using [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) method and pass the necessary key as an argument.

Following is a quick demo of that approach:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('myForm')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const formData = new FormData(form),
        formEntries = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
  console.log(formEntries)
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm"><input id="user_role_ids" name="user[role_ids]" type="hidden" value="2"><div class="control-group"><label for="user_email">Email</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email"></div></div><span id="erroremail" class="rightCol error"></span><div class="control-group"><label for="user_name">Name</label><div class="controls"><input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text"></div></div><div class="control-group"><label for="user_last_name">Last Name</label><div class="controls"><input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text"></div></div><div class="control-group"><label for="user_username">Name by which you publish</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="user[username]" id="user_username"></div></div><div class="control-group"><label for="user_country_code">Country</label><div class="controls"><select id="user_country_id" name="user[country_id]"><option value="">Country</option><option value="3">Afghanistan</option><option value="6">Albania</option><input type="submit" /></form>
```

If, for whatever reason, you need more *low level* access to the child inputs of a form (corresponding DOM-nodes and their attributes), you may go for [`HTMLFormElement.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) property which returns `HTMLCollection` of all the child nodes, so you may traverse that (e.g. with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method) to build up an object of key value pairs:

```
const formData = [...form.elements].reduce((r,{name,value}) => 
   (value && (r[name]=value),r),{})
```

You may check out the demo for that, just as well:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('myForm')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const formData = [...form.elements].reduce((r,{name,value}) => (value && (r[name]=value),r),{})
  console.log(formData)
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm"><input id="user_role_ids" name="user[role_ids]" type="hidden" value="2"><div class="control-group"><label for="user_email">Email</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email"></div></div><span id="erroremail" class="rightCol error"></span><div class="control-group"><label for="user_name">Name</label><div class="controls"><input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text"></div></div><div class="control-group"><label for="user_last_name">Last Name</label><div class="controls"><input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text"></div></div><div class="control-group"><label for="user_username">Name by which you publish</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" value="" name="user[username]" id="user_username"></div></div><div class="control-group"><label for="user_country_code">Country</label><div class="controls"><select id="user_country_id" name="user[country_id]"><option value="">Country</option><option value="3">Afghanistan</option><option value="6">Albania</option><input type="submit" /></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet all forms could be retrieved via

```
document.forms
```

Then concrete form could selected, e.g. first form `document.forms[0]`.

The next step is to retrieve form inputs and get their `names or values`:

```
document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('input')[0].value
document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('input')[0].name

// or iterate over form inputs
[...document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(input => {
  console.log(input.name);
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try grabbing direct id of the input and target its value?

const a = document.getElementById("user_email")

then a.id and a.innerValue works fine